# Debian 9.3 dist upgrade - OpenSSH service failed to start

Tags: ssh, debian

I'm too noob in Linux to handle it on my own.

I upgraded my dist today to Debian 9.3. During the upgrade the SSH server failed to start

```
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.4p1-10+deb9u2) ...
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "restart" failed.
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-14 10:38:19 CET; 4ms ago
  Process: 13714 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 13712 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13714 (code=exited, status=255)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─771 /usr/sbin/sshd

Dec 14 10:38:19 hostname systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Dec 14 10:38:19 hostname systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, co…n/a
Dec 14 10:38:19 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell…er.
Dec 14 10:38:19 hostname systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 14 10:38:19 hostname systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exi…e'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
```

I run `sshd -T`

```
port 22
addressfamily any
listenaddress [::]:22
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
usepam yes
logingracetime 120
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
streamlocalbindmask 0177
permitrootlogin without-password
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
pubkeyauthentication yes
kerberosauthentication no
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
kerberosticketcleanup yes
gssapiauthentication no
gssapikeyexchange no
gssapicleanupcredentials yes
gssapistrictacceptorcheck yes
gssapistorecredentialsonrekey no
passwordauthentication yes
kbdinteractiveauthentication no
challengeresponseauthentication no
printmotd no
printlastlog yes
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
permittty yes
permituserrc yes
strictmodes yes
tcpkeepalive yes
permitemptypasswords no
permituserenvironment no
compression yes
gatewayports no
usedns no
allowtcpforwarding yes
allowagentforwarding yes
disableforwarding no
allowstreamlocalforwarding yes
streamlocalbindunlink no
useprivilegeseparation sandbox
fingerprinthash SHA256
pidfile /run/sshd.pid
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
versionaddendum none
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
hostbasedacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
hostkeyalgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
pubkeyacceptedkeytypes ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
loglevel INFO
syslogfacility AUTH
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
authenticationmethods any
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
maxstartups 10:30:100
permittunnel no
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
permitopen any
```

I'd appreciate any advices to dig into it, including explainations to understand the issue.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/daemon.log` or try run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/log/deamon.log` revealed nothing.
Invoking `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` shows the port was already in use.
I couldn't stop the service - I don't know why.
I restarted the system and everything works fine now.